# Should common-module be declared as a peer-dependency for published angular 4 modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

In [this how-to-build-and-publish-an-angular-module](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/how-to-build-and-publish-an-angular-module-7ad19c0b4464) it says that if the module you are publishing needs the [common-module](https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule) then it should import it.  IIUC the [BrowserModule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/platform-browser) also includes the [common-module](https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule) and has to be imported by all application modules.  Should we therefore specify the [common-module](https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule) as a peer dependency when creating puslished modules?

Comment: if it can't work without it, probably yes :)

Comment: As i understand it, only the app root module should import BrowserModule. Modules imported into the root module should themselves depend on CommonModule when required.